# How is the electric potential of a localized charge distribution scaled when scaling the geometry of the problem?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, scale-invariance

I am trying to find the potential at a point on the surface of a charged polygon (rectangular). I have find a solution to the problem, but it relies on the following statement:

*If the potential at $\vec r_0$ for a localized charge distribution be $V_0$, if you scale the charge distribution $n$ times, the potential at the point $n\vec r_0$ would be $nV_0$.*

I want to know if this statement holds generally. I think it can be proved by using the linearity of Maxwell equations, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me whether the total charge is also scaled, or you want that to be conserved. So I will work under the assumption of the former case and show that the potential scales as $n^2$.

The new density $\rho'$ is related to the old density by
$$\rho'(\mathbf r) = \rho(\mathbf r/n).$$
Denoting by $\Omega$ the support of $\rho$, we have
$$V_0 = k\int_\Omega\frac{\rho(\mathbf r)}{|\mathbf r_0 - \mathbf r|}\text dV,$$
where $k$ is the usual $\frac1{4\pi\epsilon}$ and $\text dV = \text d^3\mathbf r$.

The new potential at $n\mathbf r_0$ is then given by
$$V'_0 = k\int_{\Omega'}\frac{\rho'(\mathbf r)}{|n\mathbf r_0 - \mathbf r|}\text dV,$$
where $\Omega'$ is the rescaling of $\Omega$ by the wanted factor of $n$. Using the above expression of $\rho'$ in terms of $\rho$ one has
$$\begin{align}
V'_0 &= k\int_{\Omega'}\frac{\rho(\mathbf r/n)}{|n\mathbf r_0 - \mathbf r|}\text dV\\
&=\frac kn\int_{\Omega'}\frac{\rho(\mathbf r/n)}{|\mathbf r_0 - \mathbf r/n|}\text dV\\
&=\frac kn\int_{\Omega}\frac{\rho(\mathbf r)}{|\mathbf r_0 - \mathbf r|}n^3\text dV\\
&= n^2V_0,
\end{align}$$
where the change of variable $\mathbf r/n\mapsto\mathbf r$ has been used, which leads to the substitutions $\Omega'\mapsto\Omega$ and $\text dV\mapsto n^3\text dV$.

Comment: I do not assume conservation of the total amount of charge. Your answer helped me to figure out the solution. In my case, the problem is 2D (polygon) and therefore $V$ scales with $n$, but in the 3D case, it scales with $n^2$, as you have shown. So, you can add a explanation about it in your answer. Thanks.